# Is it possible to show multiline text in bootstrap modals?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm showing a modal panel and all is ok, except i can't find the way to show the message in more than one line. I use this code:

```
var modal = $('#myModal');
modal.find('.modal-body p').text('I need this text in one line. And this text in another line');
$("#myModal").modal();
```

I search and search, but nothing.
I have tryed to use "
", but it's used like the other text.
i have tryed inserting "\r\n", and nothing.

Someone can help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use br tag, it's a line breaker to html. Tag: `<br />`
Give a try with this code:

```
var modal = $('#myModal');
modal.find('.modal-body p').html('I need this text in one line. <br/>And this text in another line');
$("#myModal").modal();
```

Comment: Please change the `.text` to `.html`, I think should work

Comment: sorry, i forgot to change .text to .html. with the change all is ok.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make sure the ccs property 'text-overflow' is set to initial so it wraps. If that does not work you can use html() to overwrite the html and render the line break

```
var modal = $('#myModal');
modal.find('.modal-body p').html('I need this text in one line. <br/>And this text in another line');
$("#myModal").modal();
```